# How to describe your familiarity?

Tags: word-request, phrase-choice

Suppose a friend of mine are talking with his girlfriend about Kevin Durant, and I also like watching NBA, so I join in with them, how should I say?

1. I know Kevin Durant. This means I am familiar with KD, and vice versa.
2. I know of Kevin Durant. This means I just hear about him.

Is there an expression containing **know** which can be used in this context?

Comment: What's wrong with "I watch NBA too."? Then follow up with other stuff about Kevin Durant...

Comment: Of course I would say that, but that's not the question I want to ask. Here my scenario is just a token. @ helix

Comment: I can see that; but you commented "all of them do not fit **here**" on Jay's answer. More situations perhaps?

Comment: I think oerkelens got it！@helix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, saying that you know him would not imply that you are friends or anything.

It is absolutely normal to hear a conversation like this:

> A: I saw this movie yesterday with this really cool actor!
>   B: Which actor?
>  
>   A: John Doe, do you know him?
>   B: Oh, yes! I do know him! He's great! And those eyes of his...

Neither A nor B are likely to have ever met the actor - and the actor probably is not aware of A's and B's existence.

Answer (score 1):

"I know Kevin Durant." You are friends or associates. You see him and talk to him regularly. You certainly recognize each other on sight.

"I know of Kevin Durant." You are aware of his existence. You may or may not know anything about him. You can also say, "I've heard of ..." to express this idea.

"I know about Kevin Durant." You know something about him. You probably don't see him regularly; you may never have met him. He may or may not be aware that you exist.

Comment: Seems all of them do not fit here.

Comment: I don't know Kevin Durant. Is he a basketball player? But if you're trying to say that you know who he is and you know something about his career, but you don't know him personally, you can say, "I know about Kevin Durant." You could, of course, say many other things about him. Like, "I think Kevin Durant is a great athlete" or "I have followed Kevin Durant's career closely", etc.

Comment: He is the next Jordan. @Jay

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I don't follow sports at all. I think a pro basketball game is 10,000 people in the stands badly in need of exercise and 10 men on the court badly in need of rest. :-)

Comment: You can say that again!o(^▽^)o @Jay

Comment: Or "I'm a big fan of Kevin Durant"